# regex for uptime command in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

"uptime" command has many different outputs. I'm trying to build regex pattern to match days and minutes. Need some help on this.
Different outputs of uptime:

```
            15:22:04 up 45 days,  2:34,  2 users,  load average: 0.94, 1.17, 1.37
            15:30:12 up 21 min,  2 users,  load average: 1.56, 1.18, 1.18
            15:30:39 up 15:30,  1 user,  load average: 0.27, 0.40, 0.48
```

I tried the following but it works only for one of the output:

```
import re;
uptime_parser = re.compile('up\s+(\d+\s+\w+,\s+\d+:\d+)')
```

Expected output for each case:

1. up 45 days,  2:34
2. up 21 min
3. up 15:30

Comment: What is your expected output for each of these strings?

Comment: I want to capture after "up" until second ","
Expecting the following:
45 days,  2:34
21 min
15:30

Comment: So you'd include `2 users` and `1 user` in the second and third examples, but not `2 users` in the first one?

Comment: I do not need the user information. Just the string after "up" until before number of users

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thanks but this doesnt catch the second set of output. In the first case, it captures only until 45 days but not 2:34

Comment: Like this `\bup\s+(?:(?:\d+\s+days,)?\s*\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}|\d+\s+min)\b` https://regex101.com/r/WwTeA8/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match the different variations:

```
\bup\s+(?:(?:\d+\s+days,)?\s*\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}|\d+\s+min)\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\bup\s+` Match the word `up` and 1+ whitespace chars
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternatives

  - `(?:\d+\s+days,)?` Optionally match 1+ digits, 1+ whitespace chars and `days,`
  - `\s*\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}` Match optional whitespace chars and 1-2 digits `:` 1-2 digits
  - `|` Or
  - `\d+\s+min` Match 1+ digits, 1+ whitespace chars and `min`
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WwTeA8/1).